# Prolog : querying if something doesn't satisfy a predicate

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I'm sure this is a n00b question, but how do I ask for things which satisfy one predicate and not another?

Eg. in a database of people and ice-cream,

```
person(john).
person(jane).
person(nicholas).

likes(john,strawberry).
likes(john,mint).
likes(jane,choc-chip).
```

How do I ask for the people who don't like ice-cream, to get just nicholas?

Answer (score 1):

This query is true if `X` is a person, and there exists no `_` where `likes(X, _)` is true.

```
person(X), \+ likes(X, _).
```

`X` will evaluate to `Nicolas`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. OK I found it.

```
no-ice(X) :- 
    person(X),
    not(likes(X,_)).
```